# How can I detect image artifacts?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video, artifacts

I need to make the script that will return True if image contains visual artifacts that look like gray clusters of pixels

[Kind of artifact that I want to catch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtqkZ.jpg)

[Image I use as a sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0sAx.jpg)

For now the best idea that I've got is to create a mask for the the range of hsv shades, count non-zero values and compare this amount to the similar amount of the sample-picture without the artifacts:

```
corrupted = cv2.imread("001.jpg")
sample = cv2.imread("002.jpg")

hsv_min = np.array((0, 0, 0), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((179, 7, 255), np.uint8)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(corrupted, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hsv2 = cv2.cvtColor(sample, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max)
thresh2 = cv2.inRange(hsv2, hsv_min, hsv_max)

nz = cv2.countNonZero(thresh)
nz2 = cv2.countNonZero(thresh2)

if nz > nz2:
  print(True)
```

I want to know if there is a specific tool for that or maybe the more convenient and efficient way to do that with opencv.

Comment: video decoding glitches can have varied appearance. you should consider the change between consecutive frames.

Comment: Where is 002.jpg?

Comment: @toyotaSupra added to the description

Comment: which one is the original andthe output is?